# What will happen if a string's value is set to an expression including an object?

Tags: java, string

I wonder what functions will be called if a string's value contains an object?

For example:

```
public class A {}

 A a;
 String str = "Hello" + a;
```

Does it also call `String.valueOf(Object)` as `System.out.println()` does?

Comment: The object's "toString()" method is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [jls 15.18.1. String Concatenation Operator +](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string
>   conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a
>   string at run time.

and [jls 5.1.11. String Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four
>   ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
>
> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the
>   **toString** method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the
>   result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null"
>   is used instead.
>
> The toString method is defined by the primordial class Object
>   (§4.3.2). Many classes override it, notably Boolean, Character,
>   Integer, Long, Float, Double, and String.